# Что означает решетка и фигурные скобки в строке: WHERE id > #{lastId}?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Не силен sql запросах. И еще зачем нужен знак доллара в условии  Id > $1?

Answer (score 2):

> Что означает решетка и фигурные скобки в строке: WHERE id > #{lastId}?

Ничего. В `PostgreSQL` нет такого синтаксиса.

Скорей всего это какие-то добавления от вашего клиентского приложения или библиотеки. Например, для использования именованных подстановок параметров в запрос.

А вот синтаксисом `$число` обозначается номер параметра в запросе с использование подготовленного запроса. По протоколу используемому для `prepared stetement` в `PostgreSQL` в запросе указываются номера аргументов, сами аргументы передаются отдельно от запроса.